# Pure CSS Dropdown issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on this CSS drop down menu and I managed to reach here.

http://jsfiddle.net/iamkrishnam/3hbbvnkq/

The total width of the navigation bar is 950px.

1) The problem is the menu doesn't sit exactly on the background image. There is some space on the left. How can I remove that space so that the menu positions itself on the background bar? Like this

[image]

2) When I hover over CATEGORIES, I would like to see the drop down link text to align to left (left alight to CATEGORIES link Text. Like this

[image]

Here is the CSS

```
#navigations {
    background-image:url(http://www.prabhuvurayabari.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/navbg2015.gif); 
    width:950; align-content:center; background-repeat:no-repeat;;
    height:34px;
    font-family:Arial, "Trebuchet MS", Calibri;
    font-size:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;


}

.navs{
    z-index:5;

}
.navs ul{
    width:auto;
    list-style:none;

}



.navs ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Arial, "Trebuchet MS", Calibri;
    font-size:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;   
}

.navs ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#222;
    display:block;
    width: 190px;
    line-height:29px;
    background-color:gray;

}

.navs ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#EEC;   
}
.navs ul li ul{
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

.navs ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}

.navs ul li ul li{
    display:block;
}

.navs ul li:hover ul li ul{
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-30px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.navs ul li ul li:hover ul{
    margin-left:100%;
    border-left:4px solid #111;
    visibility:visible;
}

.navs ul li:hover ul li ul li ul{
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-30px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.navs ul li ul li ul li:hover ul{
    margin-left:100%;
    border-left:4px solid #111;
    visibility:visible;
}

.navs ul li:hover ul li ul li ul li ul{
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-30px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.navs ul li ul li ul li ul li:hover ul{
    margin-left:100%;
    border-left:4px solid #111;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Here is HTML

```
<div id="navigations">

    <div id="navs" class="navs">
      <ul>


          <li>
            <a href="#">CATEGORIES</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DVD FILMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BLU RAY FILMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3D FILMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FILM BOXSETS</a>
             <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Demo1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Demo2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Demo3</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">TV BOXSETS</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Demo1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Demo2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Demo3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Demo3</a></li>
                </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">TV SEASONS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DELIVERIES AND RETURNS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/3hbbvnkq/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reset the `padding` on the `ul` to fix the left gap.
2. Add `text-align:left` and use `text-indent` to make the drop down text align to the left edge of "C" CATEGORIES. (This is a workaround, but I cannot think of any other ideas.)
3. Adjust the `width` of the nav container to make sure it can carry all the items in the row.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/g2xk3jun/

```
#navigations {
    background-image:url(http://www.prabhuvurayabari.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/navbg2015.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:962px;
    height:34px;
    font-family:Arial, "Trebuchet MS", Calibri;
    font-size:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.navs {
    z-index:5;
}
.navs ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.navs ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Arial, "Trebuchet MS", Calibri;
    font-size:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.navs ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#222;
    display:block;
    width: 190px;
    line-height:29px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.navs ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#EEC;
}
.navs ul li ul {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
.navs ul li ul a {
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 62px;
}
.navs ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
.navs ul li ul li {
    display:block;
}
.navs ul li:hover ul li ul {
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-30px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.navs ul li ul li:hover ul {
    margin-left:100%;
    border-left:4px solid #111;
    visibility:visible;
}
.navs ul li:hover ul li ul li ul {
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-30px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.navs ul li ul li ul li:hover ul {
    margin-left:100%;
    border-left:4px solid #111;
    visibility:visible;
}
.navs ul li:hover ul li ul li ul li ul {
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-30px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.navs ul li ul li ul li ul li:hover ul {
    margin-left:100%;
    border-left:4px solid #111;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @scdr. You are awesome. You've resolved all my issues in one go. Have a great weekend. Shine on! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding:0` to your first `<ul>`... like:

HTML

```
<div id="navigations">
    <div id="navs" class="navs">
      <ul class="no-pad">
      ...
```

CSS

```
.no-pad{padding:0;}
```

and changed these to left align sub nav:

```
.navs > ul > li > a{
    text-align:center;
}
.navs ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#222;
    display:block;
    width: 190px;
    line-height:29px;
    background-color:gray;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

See [**this updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hbbvnkq/3/)

**as I realized after Zachs post, I didn't include the left alignment for the sub nav. I edited to add that. Either his or mine should do the trick.

Comment: although i fixed the small demo link issue also looked 2, and 3 revisions but looks like it still won't answer OP's question. i believe it's a hard one than we thought.

Comment: @sdcr, never edit code or linked code. If you believe the answer or code to be incorrect, say so, but **never alter the authors intent**. The linked update (rev 3) fixes the OP's issues, as far as I know. If something was missed point it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ted. It resolved most of the issues. Ted, can the sub menu text align with the word CATEGORIES and not to extreme left?

Comment: Also the menu stacks up when the browser windows width is reduced to less the width of the menu. Can the menu stay as it is instead of stacking up?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ted's answer, mine also justifies the sub-nav to the left http://jsfiddle.net/q50hpemk/1/

```
.navs ul li ul a{
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: oops missed that part :P